# How to use href attribute in lists (OL, UL) using HTML5?

Tags: html, widget, html-lists

I am trying to validade some forms using HTML5 and Bootstrap, and for a widget I tried:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label required-field">Person Type:</label> 
    <div class="controls">
        <ul class="person-field person-field-select">
            <li class="person-type-one" href="/ff/pf/add/" title="People with type one."><label for="id_person_0"><input class="person-field person-field-select" id="id_person_0" name="person" type="radio" value="F" /> Person One</label></li>
            <li class="person-type-two" href="/ff/pj/add/" title="People with type two."><label for="id_person_1"><input class="person-field person-field-select" id="id_person_1" name="person" type="radio" value="J" /> Person Two</label></li>
        </ul>
        <br class='clear' />
    </div>
</div>
```

After validating the HTML in http://validator.w3.org/check I got the errors:

**Attribute href not allowed on element li at this point.**
Attributes for element li:
Global attributes
If the element is a child of an ol element: value

I also tried using  and got the same error:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label required-field">Person Type:</label> 
    <div class="controls">
        <ol class="person-field person-field-select">
            <li class="person-type-one" href="/fornecedores/pf/add/" title="People with type one."><label for="id_person_0"><input class="person-field person-field-select" id="id_person_0" name="person" type="radio" value="F" /> Person One</label></li>
            <li class="person-type-two" href="/fornecedores/pj/add/" title="People with type two."><label for="id_person_1"><input class="person-field person-field-select" id="id_person_1" name="person" type="radio" value="J" /> Person Two</label></li>
        </ol>
        <br class='clear' />
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Which is the correct way of having href element here?

Comment: If the user clicks on the text "Person One", what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 4):

HTML syntax does not allow the `href` attribute for `li` elements at all, only for a specific set of elements (such as `link` and `a`). Browsers ignore it if you try to use it, except that they do add the attribute into the DOM (but only as accessible via `getAttribute`, not as mapped to a property of the element node), so that you could use it client-side scripting, but that’s not advisable (use `data-*` attributes instead for such things).

So it can’t be done. What did you expect the `href` attribute to do? To turn the element to a link? The closest equivalent would be to use an `<a href=...>` element inside the `li` element, so that it contains all content you have there now, e.g.

```
<li class="person-type-one" title="People with type one.">
<a href="/ff/pf/add/">
<label for="id_person_0">
<input class="person-field person-field-select" id="id_person_0" name="person" 
type="radio" value="F" /> Person One</label>
</a></li>
```

However, this would cause problems: if the user clicks on the radio button, what happens? Does that toggle the button setting, or activate the link, or both? According to HTML5 CR, the construct isn’t even valid: an `a` element must not contain interactive content like `input` or `label`. (The `label` element, too, is classified as interactive, since clicking on it may have the same effect as clicking on the control that it has been associated with.)

So if you want to have a link in a context like this, it should have a link text of its own, even though this may mean duplicating some text. E.g.,

```
<li class="person-type-one" title="People with type one.">
<label for="id_person_0">
<input class="person-field person-field-select" id="id_person_0" name="person" 
type="radio" value="F" /> Person One</label>
(info on <a href="/ff/pf/add/">Person One</a>)</li>
```

(I would not use `li` in a context like this, since the default rendering – with a bullet or a number at the start – would not be acceptable, when the item starts with a radio button. A bullet and a radio button would like double bulleting, with a black bullet and a white bullet. When you definitely don’t want bullets or numbers, it’s better to use e.g. `div` elements or a `table` element instead of `ul` or `ol`.)

Comment: The expected behavior is, if you click in any part of the widget, you get redirected to the url in href, even if you click the toggle switch. This field is a whole button in the end. Maybe using <ul>/<li> isn't the best options... You can see the look and feel of it in the image: http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/9016/0nxp.png